# Heteronormative for nuclear family structure?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms, political-correctness, gender-politics

[Heteronormative](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heteronormative) is used to refer to a world view that promotes heterosexuality as normal or preferred. It is usually in reference to sexual orientation. Is there a separate word for describing a traditional nuclear family of mother, father, and child, as opposed to single parents, elective co-parenting, etc.? I'm looking for a word relating to the family structure as opposed to sexual orientation.

Comment: Are you looking for a word to describe the structure itself, or for *privileging* that structure?

Answer (score 4):

I'd just call that a *traditional family*. Easy peasy.

Comment: To give a long answer for the sake of giving a long answer is ridiculous; the idea is to answer a question adequately. This question needed neither research nor citation. And it didn't require an explanation, either.

Comment: _DNA extracted from bones and teeth discovered at a 4,600-year-old Stone Age burial site in Germany has provided the earliest evidence for the social recognition of a family consisting of two parents with multiple children.[3]_ [Wikipedia - Nuclear Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_family).